# Can't create socket server from http module

Tags: node.js, sockets

I wanna create socket server like a Socket.io because socket.io can't work with Corona SDK. So I need custom socket server. I create socket server with using `net` module and it is work good. But I need using `http` module because I write REST API. I try create sample socket server from `http` module but have errors.

```js
var net = require('net');
var HOST = 'localhost';
var PORT = 9999;

var server = require('http').createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.end('Hello from server');
});

server.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        data = data.toString('utf-8');

        console.log(data);

        socket.write('Hello from server');
    });

    socket.on('error', function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
});

server.listen(PORT, HOST);

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {
    console.log('CONNECTED TO: ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);

    client.write('I am Chuck Norris!');
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('DATA: ' + data);

    client.destroy();
});

client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

If I run this script I got error:

```html
CONNECTED TO: localhost:9999
I am Chuck Norris!
Error: This socket is closed
    at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:692:19)
    at Socket._write (net.js:743:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:329:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:315:5)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:241:11)
    at Socket.write (net.js:670:40)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/work/projects/edorium/Server/test/test.js:49:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:178:18)
{ Error: Parse Error
    at socketOnData (_http_server.js:411:20)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:178:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:136:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:560:20) bytesParsed: 0, code: 'HPE_INVALID_METHOD' }
Connection closed
```

Why this happed and how fix this?

*Additional to answer*

I add HTTP headers to request and all works good!

Code sample below:

```js
var http = require('http');
var net = require('net');
var express = require('express');
var HOST = 'localhost';
var PORT = 9999;

var app = express();
var server = http.Server(app);
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!fff');
});

server.listen(PORT, HOST);

server.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        data = data.toString('utf-8');

        console.log(data);

        socket.write('Hello from server');
    });

    socket.on('error', function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

    socket.on('end', function() {
        console.log('Socket end');
    });
});

// Client
var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {
    console.log('CONNECTED TO: ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
    var messagae = '' +
        'GET /' +
        'Host:localhost:9999' +
        'Content-Type:text/plain;charset=windows-1251' +
        'Content-Length:6' +
        'Connection:Keep-Alive;' +
        'Hello!';
    client.write(messagae);
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('DATA: ' + data);
});

client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> at TCP.onread (net.js:560:20) bytesParsed: 0, code: 'HPE_INVALID_METHOD' }
> ```

Since you have explicitly created a HTTP server this server is expecting a HTTP request. But you are just sending "I am Chuck Norris!" which is definitely not a HTTP request. Therefore the server closes the connection.

To send a HTTP request you might use [http.request](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.11/api/http.html#http.request). Alternatively you can study the [HTTP standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) and build a proper HTTP request yourself.

Comment: Can you recomend me where I can find node.js error description like *HPE_INVALID_EOF_STATE*

Comment: @MetalEvolutionStudio: I don't know if there is explicit documentation of these codes. I just googled to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

Your client was disconnect

```
var net = require('net');
var HOST = 'localhost';
var PORT = 9999;


var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.write('Echo server\r\n');
    socket.on('data', function(data){
    console.log(data);
    textChunk = data.toString('utf8');
    console.log(textChunk);
    socket.write("================");
    });
});
server.listen(PORT, '127.0.0.1');

server.listen(PORT, HOST);

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {
console.log('CONNECTED TO: ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);

client.write('I am Chuck Norris!');
});
var i = 0;
client.on('data', function(data) {
console.log('Received: ' + data);
i++;
if(i==2)
    client.destroy();  
} );
client.on('close', function() {
console.log('Connection closed'); 
});
```